# Interrupts caused by USB Host Controller

Tags: usb, ubuntu-14.04, interrupt, interrupt-handling

If I use an USB Device with Interrupt In Endpoint (Mouse/KBD/Touchscreen), the host controller is getting the data from the Endpoint by polling this endpoint. 
So in Linux this pipe is called URB (USB Request Block) ... and this URB is initiated by the host controller. 
So data is collected by host controller - and now, I lost the path. 
I think the data is buffered to ram, maybe by the dma controller (not sure) ... and the host controller must register an interrupt to the Interrupt Controller so that the Core can handle the Interrupt coming originally from the USB-Device.
Which driver registers the interrupts to the PIC? Where is the data stored when it is polled by the host controller?

**Anyone is familiar with this?**

---

****My specs:*************
Jetson Tegra K1 with Ubuntu 14.04.4 TLS
Egalax USB Touch Screen - USB Hid device

dmesg: input: eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch EXC3000-1470-46.00.00 as /devices/platform/tegra-ehci.2/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2.3/2-1.2.3:1.0/input/input8
[   83.700372] hid-multitouch 0003:0EEF:C000.0007: input: USB HID v2.10 Pointer [eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch EXC3000-1470-46.00.00] on usb-tegra-ehci.2-1.2.3/input0
lsusb - v:
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 0eef:c000 D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd 
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Mouse
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval

Answer (score 0):

Which driver registers the interrupts to the PIC?

> EHCI driver for tegra platform registers the interrupt. Just refer the file ehci-tegra.c in "drivers/usb/host". You can add debug prints and recompile for tegra platform and this file will be built.

Where is the data stored when it is polled by the host controller?

> Data is definitely stored in the RAM. And the buffer address is actually set by the user space application.

Comment: Dear @Shaibal - what do you mean with user space application? DMA-Memory Mapping  as mentioned in ehci-tegra.c?

Comment: By user space, I meant the buffer in URB which gets overwritten by DMA buffer. URB comes from user space application. Since we need continuous physical memory for DMA, the buffer address is replaced by the dma memory which is allocated in ehci-tegra.c.